# How to copy cell value when adding new row?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to insert a new row based on the cell value.  How can I modify this to also copy the value in column A for example) to the newly inserted row?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Rng = Range("B11:B50")
    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Value = "Annual" Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target(1).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
```

To copy both A & B

```
Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value
Cells(Target.Row + 1, 2).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value
```

Comment: You should probably tell the user where in the code to put that line.

Comment: I added it after the Target (1).Offset(1,)...row.  I have two follow-up questions.  This works great except when delete the value in column B, it adds other row.  How can I prevent this?  Also, I want to use a similar set-up on another sheet, but this time the range will be in column C.  How can I copy the values from A & B into the new row?

Comment: I don't understand you first question. To add data for A & B 

Cells(Target.Row + 1, 2).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value  

Cells(Target.Row + 1, 2).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value

Comment: Thank you, I figure out my first question.  In the new sheet, I had to change the value and I forgot the "", so that was causing the problem.                      If Target.Value >= "0" Then